# Poetry: conflicting imports

Tags: python, python-import, python-poetry

My project structure:

```
.
├── pyproject.toml
├── src
│   ├── damastes
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── main.py
│   ├── __init__.py
```

`pyproject.toml`:

```
...
[tool.poetry.scripts]
damastes = "damastes.main:main"
...
```

`~/.local/bin/damastes`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys
from damastes.main import main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

With this configuration,

```
$ damastes
```

runs successfully, but

```
$ poetry run damastes
```

results in

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'damastes'
```

With modified `pyproject.toml`:

```
...
[tool.poetry.scripts]
damastes = "src.damastes.main:main"
...
```

and `~/.local/bin/damastes`, built and installed accordingly:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys
from src.damastes.main import main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

It's *vice versa*:

```
$ poetry run damastes
```

is a success;

```
$ damastes
```

results in

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

What am I missing?

UPD:

With `pyproject.toml`:

```
...
[tool.poetry.scripts]
damastes = "damastes.main:main"
...
```

run

```
$ poetry install
```

again.

Comment: go to `~/.local/bin/damastes` and see how the project is structured, and from the python interpreter try to load the `main`, once you find out the import way in python shell, update that in the `.toml` file

Comment: Could you be more specific? From `~/.local/bin`: `>>> import damastes` and `>>> import damastes.main` is a success; `>>> import src` results in `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'`. Nothing new here.

Comment: open the damates package in file explorer, you will see many file there, `main` would be probably written in `__init__.py`. try to locate `src` there. and base on directory/package structure try to access the module/function once you able to access `src` your work will be done

Comment: The project was not created with the current name and structure. One has to keep the environment in sync.

Comment: you got solution? you can post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

It looks like after any change in project structure one has to run

```
$ poetry install
```

again.